# Вызов функции из dll написанной на Delphi из C#

Tags: c#, delphi

Есть DLL написанная на Delphi. Исходников от нее у меня нет. Есть описание. Перепробовал много способов все пишут "Attempted to read or write protected memory"

вот сама функция из dll:

```
procedure getFastPhases(n: Integer; alpha: array of Real; step_t: Real; var 
  nt: Integer; var ps: array of Integer);
```

Входные данные: n, alpha, step_t

Выходные данные: nt, ps

Как вызвать эту функцию из C#?

Comment: Это полное описание функции в dll? Никаких там stdcall или safecall под конец объявления? И какая версия Delphi использовалась для создания? (емнип, у них может быть разная размерность типа real)

Comment: Спасибо за отклик, но к сожалению это все что есть больше ни чего нет, по поводу stdcall или stdsafe разработчик сказал что по его памяти ни чего нет в конце объявления

Comment: @XmaksasX вопрос актуален? Скажу сразу динамические массивы использовать при взаимодействии разных языков очень плохая затея

Comment: Да вопрос актуален, я понимаю что это плохая идея но в этой dll написана математика без которой я обойтись не могу

Comment: @XmaksasX nt это размер созданного массива?

Comment: возможно глупый вопрос -- ILSpy в данном случае не применим ?

Comment: @Alias нет не применим.

Answer (score 2):

**Правила написание dll на Delphi:**

Сразу оговорось что описанные ниже правила применимы для "крос-языковой" dll, но я очень советую если не знаете что делаете, то применять их и в случаее когда верна схема *приложение(delphi) - dll(delphi)*.

*Что можно передавать безопасно:*

- [const, var, out]Целочисленные(возможно только надо быть осторожным с int64/uint64 в 32 битной dll, но я не уверен)
- [const, var, out]Дробные single и double(real лучше не использовать)
- [const, var, out]Любые указатели на элементарные типы, структуры и
  статические массивы
- [const, var, out]WideString

*Что можно возращать безопасно:*

- Любые целочисленные
- Любые указатели

*Перадача структур:*

Со структурами нужно соблюдать осторожность и понимать что они могут передаваться как указатель в регистре или полностью в регистре значение. Также не мало важно выравнивание.

*Перерача строк, массивов:*

Никогда не передавайте и не возвращайте строки или массивы. Эти типы являются управляемыми в контексте языка Delphi, и если вы попытаетесь передавать эти типы в лучшем случаем получите AV или утечку. В худшем случае приложение может и схлопнуться.

*Исключения:*

Вы должны обеспечить обработку исключений внутри dll и ни когда не допускать их наружу. Исключения являются классами Delphi и другие языки о них ни чего не знают, из за этого поведение при исключениях может быть не предсказуемым.

*Память:*

Если вы возвращаете какой либо указатель, то вы должны обеспечить функцию в вашей dll котороя освободит эту память, тогда вызывающий после использования вашего указателя сможет его освободить. Иначе буду утечки

**Примеры:**

Код dll

```
type
  PDblArray = ^TDblArray;
  TDblArray = array[0 .. 0] of Double; // можно вместо 0 .. 0 написать 0 .. 100000, но это может привести к печальным последтсвия если объявить переменную с таким типом

// пример входного массива
procedure DllTest1(const InputArray: PDblArray; InputArraySize: Integer); stdcall;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  try
    for I := 0 to InputArraySize - 1 do begin
      // some calculation
    end;
  except
    // some handling
  end;
end;

// пример выходного массива
procedure DllTest2(var OutputArray: PDblArray; var OutputArraySize: Integer); stdcall;
var
  I: Integer;   
  Size: Integer;
begin
  try
    Size := 100;
    GetMem(OutputArray, Sizeof(Double) * Size);
    OutputArraySize := Size;

    for I := 0 to OutputArraySize - 1 do begin
      // some calculation
    end;
  except
    // some handling
  end;
end;

// пример освобождения памяти для выходного массива
procedure DllTestFree(var OutputArray: PDblArray); stdcall;
var
  Size: Integer;
begin
  try
    FreeMem(OutputArray);
    OutputArray := nil;
  except
    // some handling
  end;
end;
```

Код C#

```
[DllImport("TestDll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern void DllTest1(double[] InputArray, int InputArraySize);

[DllImport("TestDll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern void DllTest2(ref IntPtr OutputArray, ref int OutputArraySize);

[DllImport("TestDll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern void DllTestFree(ref IntPtr OutputArray);
```

**Если dll не ваша:**

Напиши свою длл обертку соблюдая правила и все буде хорошо

**PS:**

Для шарпа под рукой ни чего нет поэтому код проверял только на Delphi. И [вот](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hk9wyw21(v=vs.110).aspx) хорошие описание для шарпа как надо преобразовывать передачу массиов в шарпе

Answer (score 1):

Код Delphi

```
type
 Tr = array[0..50000] of real;
 Ta = array[0..2000] of Integer;
 {$R *.res}
 procedure getFastPhases(const n:Integer; const alpha:Tr; var step_t:Real; var nt:Integer; var ps:Ta); stdcall;
 begin
 end;
 exports getFastPhases;
```

Код C#

```
 [DllImport("Project2.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
 public static extern void getFastPhases(int n, double[] alpha, ref double stept, ref int nt, int[] p);

 private void GetFast()
  {
    int n = 0;
    double[] alph = new double[50000];
    double step = 0;
    int nt = 0;
    int[] p = new int[2000];
    getFastPhases(n, alph, ref step, ref nt, p);
  }
```

Для работы с динамическим массивом используем указатель

Код Delphi

```
type
Tr = array[0..50000] of real;
Ta = array of Integer;
{$R *.res}
procedure getFastPhases(const n:Integer; const alpha:Tr; var step_t:Real; var nt:Integer; var ps:Ta); stdcall;
var h:ta;
begin
 SetLength(h, 5);
 nt:=Length(h);
 h[0]:=19;
 h[1]:=99;
 h[3]:=89;
 h[4]:=79;
 ps:=h;
end;
exports getFastPhases;
```

Код C#

```
[DllImport("Project2.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern void getFastPhases(int n, double[] alpha, ref double stept, ref int nt, ref IntPtr p);

private void GetFast()
 {
   int n = 0;
   double[] alph = new double[50000];
   double step = 0;
   int nt = 0;
   IntPtr p1 = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(4);
   getFastPhases(n, alph, ref step, ref nt, ref p1);
   int[] p = new int[nt];
   Marshal.Copy(p1, p, 0, p.Length);
  }
```

Функция должна быть помечена "Соглашением о вызове" [calling convention](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5) это обязательное условие иначе невозможен вызов функции(возможен только из Delphi)

Comment: вариант с динамическим массивом не правильный, он может привести не к не предсказуемым последствиям. И если это весь код для работы с этой функцией у вас будет утечка памяти.